# Color linear interpolation of ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color

I am looking for any ideas about how to colorize an ellipsoid with a custom gradient style or by a `Blend` function. I would like to colorize ellipsoid as follows:

- at $(5,0,0)$ and $(-5,0,0)$ should be red color,
- at $(0,2,0)$ and $(0,-2,0)$ should be green color
- at $(0,0,2)$ and $(0,0,-2)$ should be blue color

All other points should be interpolated, respectively to their locations.

I tried to use `Blend` function, but something went wrong.

My code:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{5 Cos[u] Cos[v], 2 Cos[v] Sin[u], 2 Sin[v]},
{u, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/10}, {v, -Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/10}, Axes -> False, 
Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None, 
ColorFunction ->Function[u, v, 
Blend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {5 Cos[u] Cos[v], 2 Cos[v] Sin[u], 2 Sin[v]}]]]
```

Comment: Did you possibly mean `Function[{u,v},Blend[...]]`?

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately, it renders me something similar to arc in three-dimensional space.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code. First of all, the ranges for the parameters are in the wrong format. They should be of the form `{u, umin, umax}` etc. If you want to control the step size you could use `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`.

Secondly, as celtschk pointed out, the arguments in a pure function should be combined in a list. If you check the documentation of [ColorFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html), you'll see that for `ParametricPlot3D`, the arguments provided to the `ColorFunction` are in this case the three spacial coordinates $x, y, z$ and the two parameters $u, v$ in that order. Therefore you could define your `ColorFunction` for example as

```
Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Blend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {(x/5)^2, (y/2)^2, (z/2)^2}]
```

You would also need to set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`. With these settings, the ellipsoid then becomes something like

```
ParametricPlot3D[{5 Cos[u] Cos[v], 2 Cos[v] Sin[u], 2 Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 
  2 Pi}, {v, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 40,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Blend[{Red, Green, Blue}, 
   {(x/5)^2, (y/2)^2, (z/2)^2}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you @Heike for clear explanation! I'm not very familiar with Mathematica. I'am Matlab user, but unfortunately my University changed to Mathematica.

Comment: @user897 I would say fortunately... Welcome to the club

Comment: @user897 A high quality answer as usual from Heike.  I would like to point out that you do not need to include the trailing unused arguments in the `Function`, so you could use `Function[{x, y, z}, . . .]` (I presume she included them for didactic clarity). Also, you can use an anonymous or "pure" function, but so as not to run into precedence problems you should wrap the whole thing in `( )` until you understand more:  `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {(#/5)^2, (#2/2)^2, (#3/2)^2}] &)`

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: If fortunately or unfortunately depends on what you need. Mathematica has abilities which AFAIK are not found in Matlab (esp. symbolic calculation), but if you don't need them and have considerable experience in Matlab, having to learn a new syntax to just do the same things you already did in Matlab is a disadvantage to you. Also I'd be surprised if there was not *some* area where Matlab is better (well, there definitely exists at least *one*: executing existing Matlab code!). There's almost always a case where the more general tool is worse than a more specialized one.